# Receiving email from users by nodemailer

Tags: node.js, express, email, smtp, nodemailer

I am trying to receive email from users using nodemailer. The email will be sent from users email and received by my email. But all it doing is sending email from my email to my email though I set different email account for **from** and **to**. But when I revesre the email acounts and set **from:myemail@example.com** and **to:usersemail@example.com** this works fine. Why this is happening? How can I fix this so that I can receive emails from users? Here is the code:

```
// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: process.env.MY_EMAIL,
        pass: process.env.MY_PASSWORD,
    },
});

// Creating the email
let info = {
    from: process.env.USERS_EMAIL,
    to: process.env.MY_EMAIL,
    subject: 'Demo message',
    text: 'For clients with plaintext support only',
    html: `
    <p>This is a demo email</p>
`
};
//send the email
transporter.sendMail(info, function (err, info) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log(info);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are logged into Nodemailer with your Google account, so I don't think it will let you just send random emails on behalf of other people (who knows). You could send it to yourself as you do in the first place, but  use a Nodemailer option from the [docs](https://nodemailer.com/message/) `replyTo`. It will still come in as being sent from your email first, but if you reply to that email to contact them it will go to the reply to email.

So it would look something like this:

```
// Creating the email
let info = {
    from: process.env.USERS_EMAIL,
    replyTo: process.env.USERS_EMAIL, // <- Here we use the reply to option. 
    to: process.env.MY_EMAIL,
    subject: 'Demo message',
    text: 'For clients with plaintext support only',
    html: `
    <p>This is a demo email</p>
`
};
//send the email
transporter.sendMail(info, function (err, info) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log(info);
    }
})
```

I think this might be what you need if you want to reply to the user on their email account. Good luck :)